# Changing file permissions does not change the file permissions in C#

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I'm trying to change file permissions with the following code:

Main:

```
string path = @"c:/users/1/desktop/temp.txt"
GrantAccess(path);
```

Grant function:

```
private void GrantAccess(string fullPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

After I run the application everything goes properly but the file permissions are not changed and I still cant open the file, write or copy it.
Why is that happen and how can I change the file permissions with C#?

Comment: Your path points to a file, not a directory. Are you sure your code runs?

Comment: @Mithrandir That's should be fine but I also thought about it before I posted this post, I tried to change a directory permissions and I got the same result, the permissions didn't change.